# Java Spring JpaRepository custom query works in windows but not in raspberry pi (debian?)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, raspberry-pi

I'm pretty inexperienced in all of this, and I'm really confused by this. I'm doing a stupid restaurant lunch menu side-project. I want to run a little java spring server on my raspberry pi.

I'm running OpenJDK-11 and Postgres-11 on both my windows machine and raspberry pi.

The following custom query works on windows but doesn't work on my pi.

```
public interface RestaurantMenuRepository extends JpaRepository<RestaurantWeek, Long> {
    List<RestaurantWeek> findByWeekNumber(int weekNumber);
}
```

Any idea why?

I also tried something like

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Week w WHERE w.week_number = :weekNumber", nativeQuery = true)
RestaurantWeek findWeekByWeekIdentifierParamNative(@Param("weekNumber") Integer weekNumber);
```

and

```
Optional<RestaurantWeek> week = this.restaurantMenuRepository.findById(id);
```

Both work on my windows pc but on on the pi. So it seems like there's something weird going on. No errors are being thrown.

WeekNumber is a column. On Windows it returns a list of weeks where the given week number matches, but on pi the list is always empty, even if there should be a match.

I'm also using the other methods from JpaRepository like `.findAll()` and `.save()` and they work perfectly fine on both, data gets saved and it returns everything currently in database just fine. It's just that my custom query doesn't work on the raspberry pi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it querying the same database?

Comment: I'll try looking into that but if the save() works and I can see that the data goes to the database and findAll() returns everything in the database correctly. I also tried findById() which works. Everything works on windows and pi except the custom query doesn't work on pi.

Comment: Can you share your `RestaurantWeek` entity code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it myself. The problem was when I was looking up the current week using the Calendar class. For some reason even though I'm running the same code

```
public static int GetCurrentWeek(){
    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}
```

in multiple places, once to check if the current week exists in database, once when generating week number when I'm saving to the database and a third time to get the current week. When saving to database, it gave me the correct week number. When querying from the database, it gave me the current week number + 1. And this only happened on the raspberry pi, not on windows. I found the problem by adding a lot of logging to see each variable, and noticed that it was querying for the wrong week number, which obviously does not exists in the database, because it was saving the week with the correct number.

I switched to using java.Time

```
public static int GetCurrentWeek(){
    return LocalDate.now().get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
}
```

Which returns the correct and same week number in every scenario.

So I guess TL:DR don't use java.util.Calendar, use java.time, and make sure that the variables your code is generating are correct.